# c choose tag with display tag table

Tags: jsp, jstl, displaytag

I want to check a certain condition within a display tag table and show or not show the particular column.

```
<display:table class="displayTable" id="ItemList" 
    name="${sessionScope.myList}" requestURI="list.action" 
    pagesize="15" defaultsort="2" defaultorder="ascending" sort="list">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${(loginUserOrgId > 0) and (loginUserOrgId==ItemList.organisationid)}">
            <display:column class="colOp" href="edit.action" paramId="itemId"
                 paramProperty="itemId">Edit</display:column>
        </c:when>
    </c:choose>
</display:table>
```

But it never shows the Edit link. When I print out the value with `c:out`, it is TRUE. but the Edit column doesn't display although the condition is true.

```
 <c:out value='${(loginUserOrgId > 0) and (loginUserOrgId==ItemList.organisationid)}'/>
```

Any missing point?

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:out value='${(loginUserOrgId > 0) and (loginUserOrgId==ItemList.organisationid)}'/>
```

is printing `TRUE`.

But does it print true when you use this one ?

```
<c:if test='${loginUserOrgId > 0 && loginUserOrgId==ItemList.organisationid}'/>
     true
</c:if>
```

Always use `&&` operator for conditional AND checking in [JSTL](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/JSTLIfWithLogicalOperatorAndOr.htm)

Also you have only one `if-checking`. You have no `else` condition. So why not use simpler `<c:if>` tags like this :

```
<display:table class="displayTable" id="ItemList" 
    name="${sessionScope.myList}" requestURI="list.action" 
    pagesize="15" defaultsort="2" defaultorder="ascending" sort="list">

    <c:if test="${loginUserOrgId > 0 && loginUserOrgId == ItemList.organisationid}">
        <display:column class="colOp" href="edit.action" paramId="itemId"
             paramProperty="itemId">Edit</display:column>
    </c:if>
</display:table>
```

Use `<c:choose>` only when you need `if`---`else if`---`else` like condition checking.

```
<c:choose> 
    <c:when test="${condition}">
         true value
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
         false value
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: I don't know what is happening. It is not working for <c:if test="${loginUserOrgId > 0 && loginUserOrgId == ItemList.organisationid}"> although it should work, it doesn't display any hyperlink at all. But if I change as <c:if test="${loginUserOrgId > 0 && loginUserOrgId != ItemList.organisationid}"> it display Edit hyperlink for the true condition row. But the second condition one is not the one I want.

Comment: Try printing the values of them to check what they really contains. set a debug, or simply use `<c:out>` or `<%out.println();%>` for printing the objects in jsp.